# R: jsonlite package

Tags: json, r

I use [this manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-mapping.pdf) to generate JSON document, based on R data. But I cant get it right.

> Therefore,
>   the native R realization of these structures is a named list for JSON objects, and unnamed list for JSON arrays.

I want to make doc like:

```
{ "DATA": [
   {"VAR1":"VAL1"},
   {"VAR2":"VAL2"}
 ]
}
```

For that I use:

```
library(jsonlite)
x = data.frame (VAR1 = 'VAL1')
y = data.frame (VAR2 = 'VAL2')
json = list(DATA = c(x, y))
toJSON(json, pretty = TRUE)
```

But values stores in arrays, and `DATA` is not array. Can't get, how to do it right?

```
{
  "DATA": {
    "VAR1": ["VAL1"],
    "VAR2": ["VAL2"]
  }
}
```

UPD: use named list instead of data.frame help with one problem, but values still stores in array

```
x = list (VAR1 = 'VAL1')
y = list (VAR2 = 'VAL2')
json = list(DATA = list(x, y))
toJSON(json, pretty = TRUE)

{
  "DATA": [
    {
      "VAR1": ["VAL1"]
    },
    {
      "VAR2": ["VAL2"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: In jsonlite you either need to use the `unbox()` function or the `auto_unbox` argument in `toJSON` to encode length-1 atomic vectors as primitives instead of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jsonlite you can just create a single data frame for your `data` array:

```
df <- data.frame("VAR1" = "VAL1", "VAR2" = "VAL2")
jsonlite::toJSON(list(data = df), pretty = TRUE)
```

Gives:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "VAR1": "VAL1",
      "VAR2": "VAL2"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you really want to have separate JSON objects, you'd need something like this:

```
mydata <- list(
  list(VAR1 = "VAL1"),
  list(VAR2 = "VAL2")
)

jsonlite::toJSON(list(data = mydata), auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Do note that it is bad practice to have an array with json objects that contain different fields, see also chapter 3 of the paper you quoted.

Comment: thanks for answer, but that is not what I'm looking for, I need that each variable should be separate JSON object. Like mentioned in question:
`{"VAR1":"VAL1"},`
`{"VAR2":"VAL2"}`

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, this is behavior of jsonlite. Using rjson instead - works fine. 
From jsonlite man:

> Two edge cases deserve special attention: vectors of length 0 and vectors of length 1. **In jsonlite these are
>   encoded respectively as an empty array, and an array of length 1.**
>   This might seem obvious but these cases result in very different behavior between different JSON packages.
>   This is probably caused by the fact that R does not have a scalar type, and some package authors decided to
>   treat vectors of length 1 as if they were a scalar. For example, in the current implementations, both RJSONIO
>   and rjson encode a vector of length one as a JSON primitive when it appears within a list:

```
# Other packages make different choices:
cat(rjson::toJSON(list(n = c(1))))
{"n":1}
cat(rjson::toJSON(list(n = c(1, 2))))
{"n":[1,2]}
```

workaround:

```
library(rjson)
x = list(VAR1 = "VAL1")
y = list(VAR2 = "VAL2")
json = list(DATA = list(x, y))
toJSON(json, method = "C")
```

result:

```
[1] "{\"DATA\":[{\"VAR1\":\"VAL1\"},{\"VAR2\":\"VAL2\"}]}"
```